# Find last index value for duplicate key item in list Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am trying to find index_value for an element in the list which is duplicate

```
[%{day: "mon", name: "Doc"}, %{day: "mon", name: "Doctor"}, %{day: "mon", name: "Doctor"}, %{day: "wed", name: "Doc"}, %{day: "wed", name: "Doc"}]
```

I am only concerned about `day`.

When I try

```
list |> Enum.find_index(fn hour -> hour.day == "mon" end)
```

this gives me 0, where "mon" has 3 items.

I want to get the very last index value, anyhow my main purpose is to get use that index to get the very next value to it.

In this case , I am trying to get

```
%{day: "wed", name: "Doc"}
```

any help would be grateful, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as *index* for linked lists. Linked lists are **not** arrays.

If you are trying to get to the next value after a bunch of `%{day: "mon"}`, you might want to reduce

```elixir
Enum.reduce_while(input, :before, fn
  %{day: "mon"}, _ -> {:cont, :in}
  result, :in -> {:halt, result}
end)
#⇒ %{day: "wed", name: "Doc"}
```

or, which is arguably more readable, but less performant, [`Enum.chunk_every/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#chunk_every/4) in combination with [`Enum.find/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#find/2)

```elixir
input
|> Enum.chunk_every(2, 1, :discard)
|> Enum.find(&match?([%{day: "mon"}, %{day: day}] when day != "mon", &1))
#⇒ [%{day: "mon", name: "Doctor"}, %{day: "wed", name: "Doc"}]
```

The second/last element of the array returned is the result.